# Google Contact API : how to get the google api contact image?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-client

I am getting the below response from the google contact API :

```
   SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo
            [type] => image/*
            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/username%40domain.com/3f800ef08589236/I_BQwBZUKwmNsRvSkFXR-A
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo
            [type] => image/*
            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/username%40domain.com/3f800ef08589236
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => self
            [type] => application/atom+xml
            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/username%40domain.com/full/3f800ef08589236
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => edit
            [type] => application/atom+xml
            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/username%40domain.com/full/3f800ef08589236/1396967693060001
        )

)
```

But I am not able to fetch the image using this data, can anyone please let me know how can I get the contact image using this data?

Answer (score 1):

It's the href in the 2nd Object you've got listed there. Send an *authenticated* request to that URL and you'll get the photo.

Answer (score 0):

use the following where $client is the Object of Google_Client();

```
foreach ($temp['feed']['entry'] as $image) {
  if (isset($image['link'][0]['href']))
  {
    $photo=new Google_HttpRequest($image['link'][0]['href']);
    $photo_val=$client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($photo);
    $photo_return=$photo_val->getResponseBody();
    $imgData=base64_encode($photo_return);
    $pro_image='data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imgData .'';
  }
}
```